# Iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

Is it possible to change iframe scrolling attribute with jquery ? 
I need to change iframe css as well.

When the root document load completed i'm changing the src attribute of iframe and then i'm attaching to iframe load event with jquery this part work with successfully.

After that i'm trying to change some attributes of same iframe with jquery but that isn't work. Iframes attributes can't change and Jquery isn't give any error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have the code you're attemptinging to use?

Comment: Sure i'll prepare and send to this post

Answer (score 0):

You can set the overflow to hidden:

```
$('iframe').css('overflow','hidden');
```